# Initiation of BlueTooth Connection to Android by BlueTooth Device(Master)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a BlueTooth(BT) device (Master) which must be connected to the android device automatically, after BT device is turned on.

In my opinion it will be something like BT headset device connection to the android, i.e. while headset turned on - it's automatically initiates connection to android and connects to it. It's not acceptable to create and keep open socket for BT connections on android.

My question is it is possible to do that and how?

If there is some listener/service which run in background of android system and create some event/intent for incoming BT connection, and what is it, and how i can to get information/notification from it?

In addition it is interesting to know - how android knows that BT headset want to connect - if it receives message/packet or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I resolved my problem, here the code:
**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

And

```
<receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name="com.package.name.ConnectionReceiver" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"
            android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

also I had implemented a BroadcastReceiver subclass onReceive method which receivers and handles these actions.

Comment: I am looking at implementing this and was curious how this application has stood up in later versions? Does it still work after the changes to BLE in Android 4.3 and other communication changes in the Lollipop and Marshmallow OS?